# Split a long column to multiple columns based on fixed number of rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am learning SQL scripting. For example, I have following weather data:

```
FriApr 13
Light rain
4°C
1
3°
80%
5-10 mm
-
16 km/h E
1
SatApr 14
Mixed precipitation
3°C
-1
-2°
90%
25-35 mm
-
26 km/h NE
0
SunApr 15
Freezing rain
2°C
-4
2°
80%
20-30 mm
-
37 km/h NE
0
```

I want to split this single long column into multiple columns, after every 10 rows to see this:

```
FriApr 13    |  SatApr 14            | SunApr 15
Light rain   | Mixed precipitation   | Freezing rain
4°C          | 3°C                   | 2°C
1            | -1                    | -4
3°           | 2°                    | 2°
80%          | 90%                   | 80%
5-10 mm      | 25-35 mm              | 20-30 mm
-            | -                     | -
16 km/h E    | 26 km/h NE            | 37 km/h NE 
1            | 0                     | 0
```

and finally want to achieve this table (transpose of above)

```
Date     | Condition         | H3| H4| H5| H6 |H7      |H8| H9       | H10   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FriApr 13|Light rain         |4°C| 1 |3° |80% |5-10 mm |- |16 km/h E | 1
SatApr 14|Mixed precipitation|3°C|-1 |2° |90% |25-35 mm|- |26 km/h E | 0  
SunApr 15|Freezing rain      |2°C|-4 |2° |80% |20-30 mm| -|37 km/h E | 0
```

I am using MS SQL server 2014, and tried to search on it but couldn't find any solution. Could anyone please help on it ?

Comment: Every ten rows determined by WHAT order? There is no inherent ordering of data in a table. You'll have to specify which column holds the ordering that gave you the result that you've copy/pasted here. Perhaps share any other columns for these records that are present as well since those may help shape the answer.

Comment: I would first put the transposed column names into the original dataset in a second column corresponding to the first columns values - that way you can pivot/partition on those values as u need

Comment: is your weather data in a form of a file? or data column in a table of a database?

Comment: What searches did you try?

Comment: Where is this data coming from? Can't you manipulate it into the shape you want it **before** it gets to the database?

Comment: Thanks All for your responses, as I am a beginner on this and may not fully understand what you are asking/suggesting. I actually copied/pasted this data from [weathernetwork](https://www.theweathernetwork.com/ca/14-day-weather-trend/ontario/mississauga) for 14 days into an excel file. The data comes in one column (as one can copy paste above data into an excel sheet), I can do the splitting job in excel and then make a database in SQL. But I was wondering whether is this doable in SQL. I didn't want to touch the order, just wanted to split this one column by a fixed-length (10 rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doable, but a little ugly.  Assuming the source is one long string.

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) ='FriApr 13
Light rain
4°C
1
3°
80%
5-10 mm
-
16 km/h E
1
SatApr 14
Mixed precipitation
3°C
-1
-2°
90%
25-35 mm
-
26 km/h NE
0
SunApr 15
Freezing rain
2°C
-4
2°
80%
20-30 mm
-
37 km/h NE
0
'

;with cte0 as (
        Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
              ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
        From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@S,char(13)+char(10),'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i) ),
      cte1 as ( Select *,Grp = max(case when right(RetSeq,1)='1' then RetSeq End) over (Order by RetSeq) from cte0 ),
      cte2 as ( Select *,RN = Row_Number() over (Partition By Grp Order by RetSeq) From cte1 )
Select [Date]    = max(case when RN=1  then RetVal end)
      ,Condition = max(case when RN=2  then RetVal end)
      ,H3        = max(case when RN=3  then RetVal end)
      ,H4        = max(case when RN=4  then RetVal end)
      ,H5        = max(case when RN=5  then RetVal end)
      ,H6        = max(case when RN=6  then RetVal end)
      ,H7        = max(case when RN=7  then RetVal end)
      ,H8        = max(case when RN=8  then RetVal end)
      ,H9        = max(case when RN=9  then RetVal end)
      ,H10       = max(case when RN=10 then RetVal end)
 From  cte2
 Group By Grp
 Having max(case when RN=1  then RetVal end) is not null
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Wow, I can see huge effort there, thanks a lot for this. But I was expecting something simpler. I mean, is it possible if a one column database imported in SQL server to apply a fixed-length splitting on it? I have copied/pasted above data in one columns of an excel file, imported in SQL server and then want to play with it.

Comment: @Asif Honestly not a huge effort.  I'm a master of cut-n-paste.  :)   Still not clear if you data is one string or multiple rows in a table.  If table, what is the primary sort?

Comment: Thanks :) My data isn't a string, it is a table with one column. My problem is similar to [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44598/need-to-divide-single-column-into-multiple-columns) (please see first part of answer and assume that one column has name 'C'). He is splitting a column by a fixed-length 5 (in my case 10). But his solution doesn't return sorted 1,2,3,4,5 (first row) & 6,7,8,9,10(2nd row). I want order to remain same even after split.

Comment: @Asif Since there is no HARD sequence/order on your records, it is impossible to ensure the proper order.  NOW, if you have another column which controls the order, then this can be simplified.

Comment: Alright, I got your point, and learned a lot from your answer. Thanks again, cheers